# How do I set a log4j2 configuration file for heroku in my scala play application?

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework

I have been trying to deploy a scala play application to heroku but I keep getting the same error:

2021-04-29 15:44:22,696 shutdown-hooks-run-all ERROR No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
3:44:22 PM web.1 Exited with exit code null

Knowing nothing about log4j I cannot understand what I need to do to fix this. Can someone please help me fix this? Better yet, is there any way to shut down the requirement for log4j2?

Comment: see also discussion at https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-seed.g8/issues/153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by switching to sbt version 1.5.1.